# how to create a confluence page using rest api with a label

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-rest-api, confluence-rest-api

I checked the [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/latest-server/#content-createContent) and I saw how to update an existing page to add the labels.

What I need is to create a new confluence page with a specific label that is added during this creation.

With get I saw that for a existing page, labels are stored into the metadatas:

```
 "metadata": {
    "labels": {
      "results": [
        {
          "prefix": "global",
          "name": "labelName1",
          "id": "2195459"
        },
        {
          "prefix": "global",
          "name": "labelName2",
          "id": "2195460"
        }
      ],
      "start": 0,
      "limit": 200,
      "size": 2,
      "_links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/2129921/label"
      }
    },...
```

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to create a page with a label and if yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is not way to define labels when the page is created.

Comment: Did you manage to create a page with labels in a single call? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation (https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#content/{id}/label-addLabels), you can add the following to your json for creating the page:

```
    "metadata": {
        "labels": [
            {
                "prefix": "global",
                "name": "label1"
            },
            {
                "prefix": "global",
                "name": "label2"
            }
        ]
    },
```

I have not, however, been successful at getting this implementation to work yet. It seems to be ignored when I invoke the post to the endpoint (/rest/api/content).

Comment: This is the addLabels part of the documentation that explains how to add a label to an existing page. What I wanted is to create a page with a label in a single request.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests and found out that if you add below json node just after `body` node a `curl` will create the page with `label2` successfully.

```
,"metadata": {"labels": [{"prefix": "global","name": "label2"}]}
```

Comment: This does not work for Confluence server 6.13.4. What's your version?